# Row repetition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql query:

```
SELECT 
 customer.full_name, 
 transaction.transaction_amount, 
 transaction.id, 
 merchant.shop_name 
FROM 
 customers customer, 
 customers_transaction_details transaction, 
 users merchant 
WHERE 
 transaction.merchant_id = 1 AND transaction.customer_id = customer.id
```

I am trying to join three tables which consist of `customers`, `customers_transaction_details` and `users`.

`customers_transaction_details` consists of two foreign keys: `customer_id` from customers table and `merchant_id` from users table.

The result based on the query above:

[image]

By right there should be only 4 records. The first 4 records are correct but there is a repetition of 121,131,141 and 151 with no shop name. How can I fix this?

Comment: no join / join condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
WHERE 
  transaction.merchant_id = merchant.id AND transaction.customer_id = customer.id AND merchant.id = 1
```

It just needs a condition to map `transaction` and `users` tables. Setting `transaction.merchant_id=1` by itself is not enough, because the `users` table was left unlimited.

**But don't do that!**

The join syntax in that query is obsolete, and has been so for more than 20 years. Write your joins like this:

```
SELECT 
    customer.full_name, 
    transaction.transaction_amount, 
    transaction.id, 
    merchant.shop_name 
FROM customers customer 
INNER JOIN customers_transaction_details transaction ON transaction.customer_id = customer.id
INNER JOIN users merchant ON transaction.merchant_id = merchant.id
WHERE transaction.merchant_id = 1 AND
```